# Superscripts and special characters in output text file

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I am trying to create output text from R that includes special characters and superscripts. For example one thing I need to output to a text file is a text string that includes the latitude and longitude with all the necessary degrees, minutes, and seconds symbols.

For example my input latitude and longitude look like this:

263949 and 813553

and I need to create and output text file with something that looks like this:

Latitude 26°39'49", Longitude 81°35'53"   NAD27

I have parsed the input values into degrees minutes and seconds but am having a hard time adding the degree and seconds symbols to the output text file.

Comment: Title is misleading, `°, ', "` are not superscripts. There must be a package for converting numeric to lat long format, but you could also easily make custom function.

Answer (score 1):

```
lt <- "263949"
ln <- "813553"
txt <- sprintf("Latitude %s°%s'%s\", Longitude %s°%s'%s\" NAD27\n",
substr(lt,1,2),substr(lt,3,4),substr(lt,5,6),
substr(ln,1,2),substr(ln,3,4),substr(ln,5,6))
cat(txt)
Latitude 26°39'49", Longitude 81°35'53" NAD27
```

Comment: @ScottPrinos I am glad it helps. If it works for you, clicking the accept makes sense.